# MediaProjection service type not recognized in android Q

Tags: android, android-mediaprojection, android-10.0

With the new privacy changes in effect with Android Q, it is now mandatory for any app using `MediaProjection` api to specify [android:foregroundServiceType](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#foregroundServiceType) attribute in the service tag under manifest.

But recently, I noticed that though I set the `android:foregroundServiceType="mediaprojection"` there is a security exception thrown. Does anybody have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Manifest:

```
<service
            android:name=".services.MediaProjectionService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:foregroundServiceType="mediaProjection" />
```

Exception thrown:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.package.app.services.MediaProjectionService@6d0fed2 with Intent { act=com.package.app.services.action.startrecording cmp=com.package.app/.services.MediaProjectionService(has extras) }: java.lang.SecurityException: Media projections require a foreground service of type ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PROJECTION
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:4103)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:219)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1891)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7343)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:933)
     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Media projections require a foreground service of type ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PROJECTION
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2071)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2039)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1987)
        at android.media.projection.IMediaProjection$Stub$Proxy.start(IMediaProjection.java:231)
        at android.media.projection.MediaProjection.<init>(MediaProjection.java:58)
        at android.media.projection.MediaProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(MediaProjectionManager.java:104)
        at com.package.app.services.MediaProjectionService.startRecording(MediaProjectionService.java:190)
        at com.package.app.services.MediaProjectionService.onStartCommand(MediaProjectionService.java:142)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:4085)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:219) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1891) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7343) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:933) 
     Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
        at com.android.server.media.projection.MediaProjectionManagerService$MediaProjection.start(MediaProjectionManagerService.java:476)
        at android.media.projection.IMediaProjection$Stub.onTransact(IMediaProjection.java:135)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1021)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:994)
```

P.S: This is experienced on Android Q DP5 GSI with target SDK 29. The app works fine with target sdk 28 without any changes.

Comment: You need this to be a foreground service (`Media projections require a foreground service of type ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PROJECTION`). Having `foregroundServiceType` is part of that, but is the service a foreground service at runtime (via `startForeground()`)?

Comment: The service is started with `startForeground(ID, Notification)`  and I did try the new `startForeground(ID, Notification, ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PROJECTION)` method. The result is the same no mater if the service type is set in manifest or in `startForeground` method. Everything works fine if I set compileSDK to 28

Comment: `compileSdkVersion` should not have an impact. `targetSdkVersion` might.

Comment: my bad, that's what I meant. But anyway `targetSdkVersion` and `compileSdkVersion` both set to 28 works fine

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't you forget to add permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />` into `AndroidManifest.xml` ?

**UPDATE**

Make sure you call `startForeground()` **before** `getMediaProjection()`!

The best solution is to call `startForeground()` from `onCreate()` without any conditions, displaying some sort of default messages in notification. Then you can execute your logic and call `NotificationManager.notify()` with updated notification at any time.

Comment: Ofcourse, it is added. The app works fine when downgrading target sdk to 28

Comment: Take a look on my update, I just checked, the order of invocation is very important.

Comment: Can you help me with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63543414/rename-file-of-the-external-storage-which-is-created-by-app-in-android-10-worki

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Media projections require a foreground service of type ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PROJECTION..... In my cause app is crashed

Answer (score 4):

Changing the following attributes

```
android:foregroundServiceType="mediaProjection"

tools:targetApi="q"
```

in AndroidManifest.xml worked for me.

```
< service

android:name="SERVICE_NAME"

android:foregroundServiceType="mediaProjection"

tools:targetApi="q"

android:enabled="true"

android:exported="false" />
```

Comment: That worked for me also after adding <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />  to AndroidManifest and set the service as foreground service before the call to MediaProjection.